# How get middle component's instance to pass its function to child in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a component:

```
var OuterComponent = React.createClass( {
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MiddleComponent>
                    <Child parentFunctionShouldBe={this.middleComponentFunction} />
                </MiddleComponent>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

How do i pass the function that lives in the middle component? The issue is that `this` refers to the `OuterComponent`, not the `MiddleComponent`. I don't want it to be a static function, but an instance function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [ref to a component](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html), and call the method from the `this.refs.componentRef`:

```
var OuterComponent = React.createClass( {
    callMethod: function() {
        this.refs.middleComponent.middleComponentFunction();
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MiddleComponent ref="middleComponent">
                    <Child parentFunctionShouldBe={this.callMethod} />
                </MiddleComponent>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work. It says "cannot read middleComponentFunction of undefined"

Comment: The ref won't exist yet because `MiddleComponent` hasn't been created at the time the ref is being accessed.

Comment: @RyanDuffy So how would I pass it then?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var OuterComponent = React.createClass( {
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MiddleComponent>
                    <Child />
                </MiddleComponent>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var MiddleComponent = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
      children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
         <div>
           {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {parentFunctionShouldBe: this.middleComponentFunction})}
         </div>
      )
    },

    middleComponentFunction: function() {
       ...
    }
});
```

Comment: `children` should probably be required if the expectation is that additional props would be passed to children. If not, for whatever reason, it would be better to check for existence of children and then clone rather than passing a `<div>` into `cloneElement` (which will complain about invalid props because `parentFunctionShouldBe` isn't a valid attribute for a `<div/>`)

Comment: @RyanDuffy I agree about prop validation but the same could be said for any prop, `cloneElement` will however not complain if a <div /> get's passed instead of a component . As a side note passing a </div> to cloneElement will result in `<div><div />` which is valid html and `parentFunctionShouldBe` is of no consequence since it's used in react's internal reference not added as an attribute to the html.

Comment: My point was that you'll get a https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html warning as illustrated in this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lp8p1vzu/) if you pass `parentFunctionShouldBe` to a `<div />`. At least that's true as of React 15.2.

Comment: @RyanDuffy I am going to eat humble pie here as the official documentation is indeed saying that is not good practice. So thanks for the advice you are right...;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a Higher-order Component (HoC). This is a good choice if `MiddleComponent` is primarily adding markup around or capabilities to `Child`.

```
var MiddleComponent = function (Wrapped) {
    var Component = React.createClass({
        middleComponentFunction: function () {},
        render: function () {
            return (
                <Wrapped {...this.props} parentFunctionShouldBe={this.middleComponentFunction} />
            );
        }
    });

    return Component;
}

var WrappedChild = MiddleComponent(Child);
var OuterComponent = React.createClass( {
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <WrappedChild passToChild="value" />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Further, you can customize how the integration occurs if you want to use `MiddleComponent` with other types of components.

```
var MiddleComponent = function (config, Wrapped) {
    var prop = config.prop || 'parentFunctionShouldBe';
    var Component = React.createClass({
        middleComponentFunction: function () {},
        render: function () {
            var extraProps = {};
            extraProps[prop] = this.middleComponentFunction;
            return <Wrapped {...this.props} {...extraProps} />;
        }
    });

    return Component;
}

// same result as above but configurable for other use cases
var WrappedChild = MiddleComponent({prop: 'parentFunctionShouldBe'}, Child);
var OuterComponent = React.createClass( {
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <WrappedChild passToChild="value" />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```